# How do i make a batch ID for multiple inserts in sql server

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I am trying to insert multiple records on my database using a simple insert query and looping it using foreach statement. Now I want to make a Batch ID for all the rows inserted and it has to be the same for all rows inserted.  The format of the batch ID I made is like this 1004160001. How can I achieve this?

I just need suggestion guys. Thank you.

Comment: What is 1004160001? How did you come up with it? Do you want a 10-digit id? You could string up YYYY-MM-DD-HH-SS and create a 12 digit ID (or less).

Comment: the format i used there was date today(10-04-2016) plus 001 is the counter for my batch ID and it's supposed to increment only one every time the user inserts a record or even multiple records.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just insert a string value '1004160001' (or an int of course)?

INSERT INTO (batch_id, data) VALUES('1004160001', 'row data');

Answer (score 0):

SET @BatchNo = '1004160001'
Loop Start

INSERT INTO MyTable(BatchNo,Slno,Name,Amount)
SELECT @BatchNo,i,@Name,@Amount

Loop End